# ¿Como usar un componente en react?

Tags: javascript, html5, reactjs, typescript, web

Estoy Usando el componente como  una etiqueta , pero me da un error , y ya importa el archivo
[image: Ese es el ERROR]

Y Este el codigo del Navbar

```
import React ,{useState} from "react";

const navbar = () =>
{
    return(
        <div>
            <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
          <div className="container-fluid">
            <a className="navbar-brand">Navbar</a>
            <form className="d-flex">
                <input className="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"/>
                <button className="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </nav>
        </div>
        
        );
   

}
export default navbar;
```

Comment: Intenta cambiar el nombre del componente a `Navbar` con la primera letra en Mayúscula [Enlace relacionado](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los componentes no pueden estar en minúsculas, el archivo se debería llamar Navbar.js o .jsx, después dentro del componente tanto el nombre de la función como el export deben estar en mayúscula la primer letra, por último en app haces el import Navbar from "./my_components/Navbar" y finalmente dentro de app llamas al componente .

Entonces:

Nombre de archivo con primer letra en mayúscula, ej:

```
Navbar.jsx
```

Este archivo contendrá algo como:

```
import React from 'react' //Esto ya no es necesario, pero no molesta.

  function Navbar() {
    return (
      <div>
        {// tu contenido}
      </div>
    )
  }
  
  export default Navbar
```

Y luego en app.

```
import Navbar from "./my_components/Navbar";
```

Y dentro de app invocamos a Navbar de la siguiente manera:

```
<Navbar />
```

Los componentes se capitalizan, es decir llevan su primer letra mayúscula para que no se confundan con etiquetas HTML.

Espero te sirva, quedo a las órdenes.

Comment: Te sugiero leer el apartado "Como preguntar" te ayudará a que sea más claro para la gente y evitar que te cierren la pregunta, siempre pasa código pegado, no imágenes, nos permite copiarlo y hacer pruebas,, la mayor cantidad de información posible para poder ayudarte por el camino correcto. Espero lo que te pasé sirva para resolver tu problema.